# Changing the userAgent with PhantomJS is not solving the old website issue

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have an issue with PhantomJS that is rendering images that is apparently an older version of the current website. It's Google Alerts. I need to modify the "Deliver to" option and set to "RSS", but in PhantomJS's eyes, the website doesn't have this option.

[image: Image of Google Alerts rendered by PhantomJS]

I was given the suggestion to modify the `userAgent`, but I've tried many ways and there's no different on the rendered result.

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
```

My whole script.

```
'use strict'

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    isLoaded,
    controller,
    isSubmitted = false

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'

page.open('https://www.google.com/alerts', function() {

  isLoaded = true
})

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  log('Loading page...')
}

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  log('Page has loaded.')

  if (status !== 'success') {
    log('The page has failed to load.')
    exit()
  } else {
    if (isSubmitted) {
      log('Submitted!')
      clear()
      exit()
    } else {
      controller = setInterval(function() {
        if (isLoaded) {
          isLoaded = false
          fillUpInputField('input', 'PhantomJS')
        } else {
          selectRSSOption()
        }
      }, 1500)
    }
  }
}

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  log(msg)

  trace.forEach(function(item) {
    log(' ', item.file, ':', item.line)
  })
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Methods
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function exit() {
  phantom.exit()
}

function log(str) {
  console.log(str)
}

function render(name) {
  page.render(name + '.png')
}

function fillUpInputField(selector, query) {
  page.evaluate(function(selector) {
    document.querySelector(selector).focus()
  }, selector)
  page.sendEvent('keypress', query)

  render('fill_up_form.png')
  log('Rendered fill_up_form.png')
}

function selectRSSOption() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector('.show_options').click()
  })

  render('show_options.png')
  log('Rendered show_options.png')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using phantom to take some screenshots to confirm your suspicion?

Comment: Yes, of course, the image I uploaded is taken with `render` from PhantomJS. Check www.google.com/alerts, fill up the input, click "show options" and you'll see the difference: there is one extra option which doesn't appear in the shown image here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this inconsistency is quite simple: Google Alerts does not have a "deliver" option until a user is signed in to a Google account.

Try opening the page in an incognito mode in the same Chrome:

[image]

So, in order to get it working in PhantomJS you need to log in to Google first. Use `--cookies-file.txt` CLI argument to persist cookies between script runs so that you need to log in only once a month.

```
/path/to/phantomjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt /script/to/run.js
```

Comment: Ah! So it's because the user isn't logged in. This app will be used by other people. Do you recommend this same way with cookies to log-in in Alerts?

Comment: It all depends on the architecture of your application, please tell more about it. Is PhantomJS going to be used as it is? Or inside of a desktop app? Or on a server as a backend service? I'm not sure, but maybe it's better to open another question to discuss all that.

Comment: It's a Facebook app, built with NodeJS. It has AdonisJS as its API and there is where the operation to perform this task will be located. I found out Horseman module that runs PhantomJS with Node.

Comment: Then I think it's trivial for you to launch PhantomJS process with custom cookie filenames for diff. users: `phantomjs --cookies-file=cookie{$userId}.txt scripts.js`

Comment: But will these files be stored in their local machine? How's this going to work?

Comment: Where are you going to run PhantomJS - on your server or on users' computer? That's where the cookie file will be. *("Facebook app" or "AdonisJS" don't ring a bell for me)*

Comment: It's ran in the server, I suppose.